# Callgrind main() inclusive cost much smaller than 100%

Tags: profiling, valgrind, callgrind

I profiled a few very simple C++ programs running on Linux. The inclusive cost of main() for all of them is far from 100%, something like 3.83%. Am I using callgrind correctly? I have the output of `callgrind_annotate` with `--inclusive=yes` pasted below.

The program is called heap which does simple heap sort. The command I used is

```
valgrind --tool=callgrind ./heap
```

Then, I type

```
callgrind_annotate --inclusive=yes callgrind.out.25434
```

Output:

```
`--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Profile data file 'callgrind.out.25434' (creator: callgrind-3.6.0)

`--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I1 cache:
D1 cache:
LL cache:
Timerange: Basic block 0 - 361578
Trigger: Program termination
Profiled target:  ./heap (PID 25434, part 1)
Events recorded:  Ir
Events shown:     Ir
Event sort order: Ir
Thresholds:       99
Include dirs:
User annotated:
Auto-annotation:  off

`--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

       Ir
`--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2,552,558  PROGRAM TOTALS

`--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

       Ir  file:function

`--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2,552,558  ???:0x00000810 [/lib/ld-2.7.so]

2,515,793  ???:0x00000a60 [/lib/ld-2.7.so]

2,515,219  ???:0x00015270 [/lib/ld-2.7.so]

2,514,780  ???:0x000021e0 [/lib/ld-2.7.so]

2,456,164  ???:0x0000b2f0 [/lib/ld-2.7.so]

2,256,719  ???:0x00009e40 [/lib/ld-2.7.so]

1,702,371  ???:0x00009ac0 [/lib/ld-2.7.so]

  657,883  ???:0x000098e0 [/lib/ld-2.7.so]

  367,045  ???:0x00017040 [/lib/ld-2.7.so]

   33,170  ???:0x080483e0 [/home/test/heap]

   33,036  ???:0x0000ce60 [/lib/ld-2.7.so]

   31,347  ???:0x0000e850 [/lib/ld-2.7.so]

   30,706  ???:(below main) [/lib/libc-2.7.so]

   30,071  ???:0x00008570 [/lib/ld-2.7.so]

   27,954  ???:0x0000f500 [/lib/ld-2.7.so]

   27,758  ???:0x0000ca30 [/lib/ld-2.7.so]

   21,366  ???:0x0001767b [/lib/ld-2.7.so]
```

Comment: It looks like at least some of your output is missing. In particular, I don't see any inclusive cost figures. How long does your program take to run? If you arrange for it to take longer (e.g., heapsort a much longer array), does the inclusive cost come closer to 100%? Anything the runtime does before main() gets called won't get counted, so if what main() does is much cheaper than (e.g.) loading dynamic libraries then the inclusive cost could be some way below 100%. What's the shortfall in absolute units (say, ms)?

Comment: Thanks Gareth! The heap sort takes less than 1 sec. I'll make it run longer. I want to make sure I'm using callgrind correctly. Since when profiling a real application, after I removes a big bottleneck (exclusively 47%) identified by callgrind, the total run time doesn't change at all.

Answer (score 5):

The `main()` is not the top function in call graph. There is an `_start` function in glibc, which will call `main()` and it also will take return value from `main`. Also there is (for dynamically linked programs = almost all) an ELF interpreter, also known as dynamic linker (run-time): /lib/ld-linux.so (this name is used in linux, in other Unixes something like /lib/ld.so). Linker will load and initialize all dynamic libraries needed by the application; and it is called by OS before `_start`.

What is done before `main`? Loading of libraries (open library file, parse its header, mmap it, adopt code for new location in memory=relocations processing), and initialization of them (both dynamically and statlically linked libraries need this; note that glibc=libc is library too). Each library may have a code, which will be started just after loading of the library (`__attribute__((constructor))` or non-trivial constructors of global objects). Also, glibc can register some functions to be run after main (e.g. via `atexit()`; if main returns normally, they will be called by _start), and libraries may have a destructor functions for global objects.

If your program uses threads, the top function of threads `1`..`n` will be not a main (each thread can separate stack; and chain of function calls from `main` is stored in stack
of thread 0).

In your example we see /lib/ld-*.so, and it is a dynamic linker. Seems, your application execution is too short to be correctly profiled and it uses high number of dynamic libraries.